# Do struct tags throw error to the API user?

Tags: validation, go, struct, tags

```
type Person struct {
  Id       string
  Roll_no  int
  Email    string  `json:"email" validate:"required"`
}
```

The email here is required. If the user does not provide that in the request body of the API call, will Go handle the name validation automatically and throw the error if this field is not provided? Or would i neeI to validate it manually in my code and throw the error in some form of a http status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do struct tags throw error to the API user?

No. For a lot of reasons.

1. Some struct tags (e.g. the json ones) are just used by package encoding/json to map between JSON object elements and struct fields).
2. Other struct tags (like validate) are used by certain 3rd party packages and if you do not use that package nothing at all will happen.
3. Go (the language and its stdlib) is "free from magic". Nothing magically happens. If you need validation on your API endpoints you might use validation packages which inspect struct tags but this won't happen magically: You have to call these functions and return an API error yourself. And no, I won't recommend a framework here.
4. To work struct tags have to be valid, none of yours are. Run `go vet` to find this type of problem. (should be `json:"emal" validate:"required"` and probably even "email")
5. Errors in Go are not "thrown" at all. Especially HTTP responses with a status code of 400 Bad Request are not "thrown". It always helps to get the terminology correct).

Comment: so u mean i would have to check it manuallly in my code if the user has provided the email field, right?

Comment: @Ashwin You did not show enough code or explain your setup in detail enough, but just adding a struct tag somewhere doesn't _do_ anything.

Comment: ok thanks, thats what i wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON sent over API does not contain `Email` then `encoding/json` `json.Unmarshal` will treat it as if `Email` was an empty string.

Option A: If empty string is not a valid `Email`, you can check for an empty string after `json.Unmarshal`

```
    var person Person
    
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &person)
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    
    if person.Email == "" {
        return errors.New("email cannon be empty"
    }
```

Option B: If empty string is valid, you can create a custom `MarshalJSON` to parse JSON as a string and look for the `Email` key.

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-package-CustomMarshalJSON

Comment: so under which case, would golang handle it automatically? or would i need to validate it manually every time in my code to check if its provided or not?

Comment: @Ashwin Go cannot automatically return an error code over API without you adding your own handling. `json.Unmarshal` will return an error if the the raw JSON cannot be converted to your `Person` type, but `Email` missing or empty would not prevent unmarshaling. 

You would need to add your own validation for both Option A and B.

Comment: what is the use of that validate tag then?

Comment: validate tag is utilized by `json.unmarshal` method which needs to be called manually.